# js observe for field validation flickering

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I am using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('street_1').observe('keyup', function(e){
        Validation.validate($('street_1'))
    });
</script>
```

Which on `keyup` triggers my form validation:

```
Validation.add('validate-jurgis', 'Address has to be no longer than 10 charecters', function (v, elm) {
    var reMax = new RegExp(/^maximum-length-[0-9]+$/);
    var reMin = new RegExp(/^minimum-length-[0-9]+$/);
    var result = true;
    $w(elm.className).each(function(name, index) {
        if (name.match(reMax) && result) {
            var length = name.split('-')[2];
            result = (v.length <= length);
        }
        if (name.match(reMin) && result && !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v)) {
            var length = name.split('-')[2];
            result = (v.length >= length);
        }
    });
    return result;
});
```

Everything works great, except the error message flickers once when the error message should `pop-up` and disappears, screen capture to show what I am talking about.

[Screen capture](https://www.useloom.com/share/209db3ae82c94e8e8bf3849c05e49420)

**Edit**

To make the problem clear, I made another screen capture (triggered on "@" character) (see from 6th second)

[Screen capture 2](https://www.useloom.com/share/301f80c6467d4bd19397862a61e2182b#)

Comment: You want to display the error message `Address has to be no longer than 10 charecters` in a pop up ? that's what you're looking for ?

Comment: No, I like exactly how it is. But, if you take a close look at the capture, you can see, that the message is not displayed on the first "trigger" (the box turns red, but the message just flickers and disappears)

Comment: I added another capture where the problem is clearly visible

Comment: ok your problem is that you want to display your message no more and no less than 10 characters in this field right ?

Comment: No, sorry if i'm not being crear. If you pause the "screen capture 2" at 0:09 you can see that there is "@" in the field, but the error message is not displayed, that's what I don't want to be happening. You can see that when I wrote the first "@" it worked fine and displayed the message, but when I typed the second "@" the message just briefly appeared and then disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

There is a natif Magento js frontend validation form input fields functions, I replace all your js with **one** line !

Go to your field where your want to execute this condition then add the line bellow in `class=" "`

```
class="input-text validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10 required-entry".
```

You can add these classes:

`validate-number` : accept only numbers

`validate-street` : accept only letters (a-z or A-Z) or numbers (0-9) or spaces and #.'

`validate-alpha` : accept only letters (a-z or A-Z)

This will fix your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't fix my problem because this is exactly what I am doing currently, I just renamed `validate-length`  to `validate-jurgis` and placed it in a separate js file so I could play around with it.